# mysqli object variable from request key

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

Im not sure if this is possible. here is what i have

```
if ($_REQUEST[db]=="abcd"){   
    $result =$abcdsqli->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
}elseif ($_REQUEST[db]=="efgh"){   
    $result =$efghsqli-> ...
}
```

here is what i want

```
$result =$.$_REQUEST[db].sqli->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
```

Comment: Almost any time you need variable variables in your code you're probably making a mistake. Try to rethink what you are doing using arrays.

Comment: its not actually a variable variable, im trying to build an object's name FROM a variable so i can use the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need so many `mysqli` objects?

And using `$_RESQUEST` in your code so openly like that can lead to many many hacks on your site.

Just use one (**one**[1]) mysqli object.

---

I advise to **NOT USE THIS** but this is what you want:

```
$sql = "{$_REQUEST['db']}sqli";
$$sql->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
```

So if `$_REQUEST['db'] == 'abc'` It would be doing:

```
$abcsqli->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
```

Comment: i use multiple mysqli objects because im selecting from multiple databases in my private admin panel that shows statistics over 4 different websites.  i found myself needing to switch databases during a mysqli while statement to compare data to another website.. so i am trying this way

Comment: We use multiple dbo (database objects) all the time. I think the db key is simply a flag for his app to determine which dbo to use for the query.

Comment: @JohnnyCraig fine, that is fine. you did not specify that in your question. but using `$_REQUEST` for that leaves you very open to hackers.

Comment: i would have made it part of my post had i thought it was relevant to the question and/or answer.

Comment: @JohnnyCraig i added to my answer for you.

Comment: @johnny: a single db handle can query multiple dbs: `SELECT tablename.fieldname FROM dbname.tablename.fieldname ...`. As long as the user ID you've connected with has the appropriate rights,  you don't need multiple handles.

Comment: Thanks Neal that worked great.  @Marc I will try to construct my new page the way you have stated.  I appreciate the help guys

Answer (score 1):

Your question is perfect for the factory pattern using a singleton. This code is skeletal, meaning there is 0 validation, etc., but should give you an idea.

```
class Database
{
    private static $dbos = array();

    public static function getDbo($dboKey)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$dbos[$dboKey])) {

            switch ($dboKey) {
                case 'abcd':
                    $dbo = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db_1'); 
                    break;

                case 'efgh':
                    $dbo = new new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db_2');
                    break;
            }

            self::$dbos[$dboKey] = $dbo;
        }

        return self::$dbos[$dboKey];
    }        
}

$result = Database::getDbo($_REQUEST[db])->query("SELECT * FROM ...");
```

Comment: will this build a new mysqli object if there isnt one? and if there is it will return the object so i can use it? this is a nice function

Comment: You got it. A factory is a blackbox algorithm that will return a known object based on minimal input, which this does. When you pass it a key, it will direct the factory on how to construct the object, and return it.

Comment: what is the exact "name" for this type of functionality? I would like to read more about it and see how I can apply it to other things. I always knew there was something that worked this way but didnt know how to find it without the name.

Comment: Setting a static var which houses values and used in this manner is known as a 'singleton'. The method `getDbo()` follows the factory design pattern.

Comment: i appreciate your time. im excited to implement this. i sent u some points