# Too many open MySQL connections

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a project in which two portions of webpage frequently change and fetch recent data. I have some confusion about whether to use `mysql_connect` or `mysql_pconnect`?  I have one config file that is being included in every page. There is one database connection object which I use for queries. Even when approximately 70 users are online it shows 20,000 connections on my server. Please suggest me the best way to keep a single connection alive from a single user, so there should be 70 connections when there are 70 users online.  Currently I'm not using `mysql_close` method to close connection. Is this the reason it shows these many connections?  Your advice will really be appreciated.

Comment: Why weren't useful for your problem the other questions already present here in [SO] that are related to the same issue? You can look for them at the right bar of this page, just below the block for Careers 2.0.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but your issue really is that you are not disposing of the database connections appropriately.

Comment: You may run into this issue when using `mysql_pconnect`. If you're using `mysql_connect` it's fine not to call `mysql_close` as the connect will be dropped when the script has finished executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern used in this case is the singleton pattern, here's some rough code.

```
class DB_Instance
{
    private static $db;

    public static function getDB()
    {
        if (!self::$db)
                self::$db = new Database(); 

        return self::$db;
    }
}


function getSomething()
{
    $conn = DB_Instance::getDB();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Some examples/references

http://tutorialpedia.org/tutorials/Singleton+pattern+in+PHP.html
http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/php/mysql-v3/Database.singleton.phps
http://netlinxinc.com/netlinx-blog/53-php/7-applying-the-singleton-pattern-to-database-connections-in-php.html

Comment: Well, common is true, but whether it's good is probably up for debate :)

Comment: What pattern do you suggest instead ? We use this at work and never had a problem with it.

Comment: Factory pattern doesn't solve instantiating multiple classes. It only helps in mitigating tight coupling between classes. If you did use the factory pattern you would still have to use a singleton pattern within the factory pattern for the database to only create one single instance.

Comment: @ Interstellar_Coder: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.  I will follow singleton pattern in db connection.  It seems that this will solve my problem of more open connections. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my implementation maybe it is useful for you

```
<?php
    class Utils_Sql{
        private $count = 0;
        private static $sqlObj = null;
        /** 
         * @return Utils_Sql 
         */
        public static function getSql(){
            if(self::$sqlObj===null){self::$sqlObj = new Utils_Sql();}
            return self::$sqlObj;
        }
        private $db;
        private function __construct(){
            $this->db = mysql_connect(MYSQL_SERVER,DB_LOGIN,DB_PASS);
            if($this->db === false){
                Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log(
                    array("Unable to connect to DB on Mysql_Server:".MYSQL_SERVER." with login:".DB_LOGIN." and pass:".DB_PASS."!")
                    ,Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_ERROR
                 );
            }else{
                if (!mysql_select_db ( DB_NAME , $this->db )) {
                    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE " . DB_NAME;
                    $this->qry($sql);
                    if (!mysql_select_db ( DB_NAME , $this->db )) {
                        Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log(
                            array("DB: ".DB_NAME." not found"),
                            Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_ERROR
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        mysql_set_charset  ('utf8',$this->getConnection());     
        }    
        public function getConnection(){return $this->db;}
        public function qry($sql,$errType,$errMsg=""){
            $this->count++;
    //      Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log("<br>$sql<br>",Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_LOG);
            $ret = mysql_query($sql,$this->getConnection());
            if(mysql_error($this->getConnection())){
                //Error
                $msgs = array(
                    "mysql_error: (".mysql_error($this->getConnection()).")",
                    "qry: \"$sql\""
                );
                if($errMsg!==""){$msgs[]="$errMsg";}
                Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log($msgs,$errType);
            }
            return $ret;
        }
        public function getData($sql,$errType=Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_ERROR){
            $r = $this->qry($sql,$errType);
            if($r === false){
                Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log("No Sql Resource, Illegal Query!",$errType);
                return false;
            }
            $ret = array();
            while(($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))!==false){
                $ret[] = $data;
            }
            if(count($ret)===1){return $ret[0];}
            else if(count($ret)>1){return $ret;}
            else{
                $msgs = array(
                    "No resulset found.",
                    "qry: \"$sql\""
                );
                Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log($msgs,$errType|Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_WARNING);
                return false;
            }
        }
        public function getInsertId($sql,$errType=Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_ERROR){
            $this->qry($sql,$errType);
            $ret = mysql_insert_id($this->getConnection());
            if(!is_numeric($ret)){Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log("mysql_insert_id is not numeric!",$errType);}
            return $ret;
        }
        public function getDbName(){return DB_NAME;}
        public function __destruct(){
    //        Utils_Logging_Logger::getLogger()->log("Querys count: '$this->count'",Utils_Logging_Logger::TYPE_LOG);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interstellar_Coder is correct, you want to use a singleton/factory solution for your db connection handling. We use here at work and it serves us well.

While Interstallar_Coder's solution is valid, I wrote up a more flexible solution in response to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987717/mysqli-object-variable-from-request-key/7987850#7987850).

Destroy db connections:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    foreach (self::$dbos as $key => $dbo) {
        self::$dbos[$key] = null;
    }
}
```

More info about PDO [connection management](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Comment: @ Digital Precision : Thanks a lot for your suggestion.  I implemented singlton solution.  Do I need to close db connection if I use singlton?  Because in my project I need to refresh one section every second.  So open and close db connection is feasible in this kind of situation?

Comment: @Naresh: Good question, yes you should explicitly destroy your connections. However, you do not want to do this from calling code, otherwise you will defeat the purpose of the singleton. My suggestion is to add a __destruct() method to the database class, and manually close each connection by setting it to null.

Comment: @Naresh: Also, if you are polling a database every second like you indicated, you may want to introduce a caching layer to ease the burden on your database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you explain about this caching layer?  I never heard about this before.

Comment: @ Digital Precision : Can we use file operations here.  If we manage separate text file for all the users and update them according to user actions and display file content, then this will reduce all database connection set up and queries.  Can you give me your suggestion here?

Comment: @NareshChauhan: I would recommend against using flat-files as you will end up ratcheting up your disk I/O. Caching refers to the ability to store key/value pairs within a highly optimized storage built for fast writes and reads. Good place to start is http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php

Comment: @ Digital Precision : Can you explain what do I need to write in destructor?  Instance of class is $instance in my class.  But when I replace $dbos  with $instance in the destruct method it shows me error Cannot use object of type dbclass as array .

Comment: @NareshChauhan: The code should be implemented verbatim, and should work fine. The __destruct() method is called there are no other references to the class, or during the shutdown sequence, basically no matter what the __destruct() will be called. More info @ http://us2.php.net/destruct