# Too many connection while using a persistent connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a small blog with more than 400 online visitors per minutes.

Since there is many connection request needed I'm using a persistent connection to reuse it when it's possible, here is my connection class:

```
<?php
    class DatabaseConnection {

        var $currCon;

        public function connect() {
            require_once '/config.php';

            try {

                $this->currCon = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8", 
                    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
                ));

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
                header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
                header('Retry-After: 300');
                die("Can't connect to MySQL database<br />: " . $e);
            }
        }

        public function disconnect() {
            // Unused for PERSISTENT connections
            // $this->currCon = null;
            // unset($this->currCon);
        }

        public function getDatabaseConnection() {
            return $this->currCon;
        }
    }
?>
```

The problem is that I got many errors which said ***Too many connection*** and That's interesting because I'm using persistent connection model!

Also I changed my `MySQL` service config and increasing `max_connection` value from 150 to 500 but the problem still persist!

Any ideas to how avoid from this error!?

Comment: are you creating new object for DatabaseConnection each time? if so then each instance of DatabaseConnection class will have separate $currCon which means for each instance there will be new connection to database. I suggest using singleton approach to solve your issue.

Comment: @lihsus Yes I create new instance per request, So you suggest me to use Singleton?

Comment: Singleton won't make number of connections less than number of requests. It just can help you to make sure you you are using no more than one connection per request

Comment: yes, make the connect() function static : `public static function connect()`, and create a private constructor.. `private function __construct()`

Comment: @lihsus How about changing `$currCon` to private static?

Comment: if you are sure that connect() is called only once per application, then singleton will help nothing.

Comment: I found another thread that discusses similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086059/too-many-open-mysql-connections

Comment: @NullPointer, yes you should also make `$currCon` private static.

Answer (score 1):

1. make it

   ```
   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE
   ```

   most likely this will be enough.
2. Also make sure you are calling DatabaseConnection::connect() only **ONCE**

Comment: I follow this answer and still get `Too many connections` error! Any ideas?

Comment: It's hart to tell just out of the head. Most likely you are still connecting more than once per application. Also there could be slow scripts that fail to release the connection. It could be that your changes to mysql config didn't applied actually. However, even 150 should be enough for the 400 per minute (unless extensive ajax-based pinging is used)

Answer (score 0):

In such type of application the better approach would be **not to use** a persistent connection at all. If the MySQL server is on the same machine, the benefit of the persistent connection is minor.

This has been already discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323928/1800369